# Include header from Aggregate Report

Tags: jmeter

I am beginner to JMeter. I am successfully able to store the aggregate report in a csv output file. But I am unable to save the headers. 
Can you please tell me how to store the header of the aggregate report in CSV output file ?
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to check `Save Field Name(CSV)` in the configuration settings for files given on right of the file name in Aggregate report?

Comment: Tried that but it does not help :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved my problem :-)

- Tick the include group name in label
- Tick Save table Header in the aggregate report section at the bottom